# What is this black streak on the F-35B?

Tags: fighter, f-35

I was seeing [this image](https://www.airliners.net/photo/Italy-Air-Force/Lockheed-Martin-F-35B-Lightning-II/7279447/L) and noticed a black streak behind a vent on the fuslage of the F35. What is this vent used for?

[image]

Comment: [Details](https://qph.cf2.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-36bda30f43846458948d85ecaa673e18-pjlq) between the auxiliary intake and the lift fan ([source](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-intake-thing-behind-the-F-35Bs-VTOL-door)) - [Model](https://modelsport.no/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/2-60791f.jpg) - [Top view](https://www.codeonemagazine.com/images/media/20100324_BF2_Goatee_01_1267828237_6178.jpg)

Comment: I edited your answer for clarity. Your use of the word “smoke” was not really correct. None of the photos online show smoke coming out of the vent, but some do show a black residue on the fuselage. It appears that that some of the engine exhaust is vented from that hole, and it leaves a sooty stain on the aircraft. It would be nice to see what the answer is.

Comment: @MikeSowsun Ok, Thank you Mike.